# How to remove special characters before JSON.parse() while file reading

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i have a `json` within a folder that comes from **third party** i don't have control on `json` data just i need to `parse` it and manipulate.

**some time i will get this error:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse

json is valid json but due to some special character i get above error:

> R:\30-09-18\LTP\p

**some time i will get parse error:**

> unable to parse .........

**Question:** how can i remove all special characters so that `JSON.parse(data);` will not throw any `error`

**here is what i'm trying:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fileLoc = path.join(__dirname,'file.json');
var content = fs.readFileSync(fileLoc,'utf8');
content = JSON.parse(filecontent);  // error occurs here
```

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you sure that the `JSON` string is valid?

Comment: @vibhor1997a, i'm 100% sure that json is valid one, i have checked in `json lint`, **BUT** contains some special characters.

Comment: what is special characters? Do you have any sample?

Comment: @MiladAghamohammadi, it will differ sometime `R:\30-09-18\LTP\p` this make **Unexpected end of input** and so on

Comment: well, its kinda not clear becouse we gonna need to see the whole Json.
I mean, what u posted is seems to be ok if its inside JSON.

Comment: Just before parsing replace special characters with something.

Comment: @Abhishek, that is what i'm thinking but don't know how to implement it

Comment: Can you try this in console

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var JSONObject = { "a":"R:\29-09-18\LTP\p"}
    var str = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
    str = str.replace(/[!@#$^&%*()+=[\]]/g, '')
    console.log(JSON.parse(str))

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: @Abhi by `str.replace(/[!@#$^&%*()+=[]]/g, '')` you are removing some characters that cause changing content

Comment: @MiladAghamohammadi, i know that, my question is during file read how to use that , before trapping into any **error**

Comment: @Faheem, please try to understand the question, in `nodejs` context , the `data ` comes in `buffer` then it has to be `parsed` then the above operation(Duplicate one) can be performed. **NOW Problem** is during parsing

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround to replace special characters preserving them

```js
const replacer = str => ({
  '\t': '\\t',
  '\n': '\\n',
  '\b': '\\b',
  '\r': '\\r',
  '\f': '\\f',
  '\\': '\\\\',
  '': '\\\\'
}[str]);

const regEx = new RegExp('\\\\|\t|\n|\b|\r|\f', 'g');

const replacedText = text.replace(regEx, replacer);
const object = JSON.parse(replacedText);
```

> The only character I can't manage is `\"`

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fileLoc = path.join(__dirname,'file.json');
var content = fs.readFileSync(fileLoc,'utf8');
content = content.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
content = JSON.parse(filecontent);
```

When you want parse a string that contain backslash character, you should change every backslash with two backslash. below is an example run in console tab of chrome browser

```
content = '{"path":"R:\\30-09-18\\LTP\\p"}'
JSON.parse(content)
VM835:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 12
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
(anonymous) @ VM834:1
content = content.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
"{"path":"R:\\30-09-18\\LTP\\p"}"
JSON.parse(content)
//result is {path: "R:\30-09-18\LTP\p"}
```

Comment: that is what i asked here how to remove them dynamically without getting trapped into above error

Comment: (/[!@#$^&%*()+=[]]/g, '')  these are the special characters, you need to hard code them in your code. " remove them dynamically" means what? .. You dont have control on that json, you need to parse as mentioned by me or Milad. What you are expecting?

Comment: `content = content.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')` line in answer is your solution if your spatial character is backslash.

Comment: Your error is during parsing, right? One line before parsing, use `content = content.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')`

Answer (score 0):

I used Gabriel Rodríguez Flores's solution, but added double quotes:

```
const replacer = str => ({
            '\t': '\\t',
            '\"': '\\\"',
            '\n': '\\n',
            '\b': '\\b',
            '\r': '\\r',
            '\f': '\\f',
            '\\': '\\\\',
            '': '\\\\'
        }[str]);

        const regEx = new RegExp('\\\\|\t|\n|\b|\r|\f|\"', 'g');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34123637)